# Экранирование обратных кавычек в heredoc для sql-запроса

Tags: mysql, bash

Я написал небольшой сценарий на bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS=" " read LITRAGE FLOW T1 T2 ;

do echo $LITRAGE $FLOW $T1 $T2;


mysql -u admin-um -pdrums um-jekeha << EOF
use um-jekeha;
INSERT INTO main
(date, litrage, flow, t-hot, t-cold)
VALUES
(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), $LITRAGE, $FLOW, $T1, $T2)
EOF

done < ./log 
exit 0
```

и когда я запускаю его в консоли, имею такую проблему:

```
iam@workstation:~/projecto/um/soft$ sh base1.sh 
11.50 0.70 24.33 25.33 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-hot, t-cold)
VALUES
)' at line 2URRENT_TIMESTAMP), 11.50, 0.70, 24.33, 25.33
```

11.50, 0.70, 24.33, 25.33 << это верные переменные из "log".

Пробовал по-разному экранировать обратными апострофами - на них ругается, пробовал и без, и кавычки. Ничего не помогает.

В чём может крыться проблема?

Comment: Западные друзья помогли, проблема в "-" названии колонок.

Comment: попробуйте `<< 'EOF'`, чтобы bash не обрабатывал содержимое here-doc, и взять название колонок в обратные апострофы/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скорее всего, имена столбцов здесь:

```
(date, litrage, flow, t-hot, t-cold)
```

содержащие не-цифро-буквенные символы, надо заключить в «обратные кавычки» <kbd>`</kbd>, а чтобы они не интерпретировались оболочкой как команды, добавить перед кавычками обратные слэши <kbd>\</kbd>:

```
(date, litrage, flow, \`t-hot\`, \`t-cold\`)
```

---

**ответ на комментарий**

> сейчас две записи делает, одну полностью нулевую, вторую с данными

вероятно, во входных данных присутствует пустая строка. чтобы исключить обработку пустых строк, можно проверять на пустоту, например, первую из получаемых переменных. для этого сразу после `do` вставьте проверку. вместо:

```
do echo $LITRAGE $FLOW $T1 $T2
```

напишите, например:

```
do
[ -z "LITRAGE" ] && continue
echo $LITRAGE $FLOW $T1 $T2
```

Comment: тогда `date` то же на всякий случай в апострофы, все таки тип данных и функция ...

Comment: @Mike, в соответствии с золотым правилом «не сломалось — не чини», лучше не исправлять то, на что программа не «ругается».

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. ) Поступил проще, убрал тире из названий столбцов. ) Единственное, сейчас две записи делает, одну полностью нулевую, вторую с данными.

Comment: @Sherst, я дополнил ответ.